# Power Bi con filtros

Tags: excel, powerbi

Filtros:

Los filtros que pongo en el report, los podrá ver quien utilice el report publicado? Es decir, tengo un filtro puesto para solo mostrar CA como cliente y que no vea el resto de clientes. Si publico esto CA podrá ver este filtro y ve el resto de clientes?

Si no quiero que vean el resto debería hacer el filtrado en la query (transform data)? De esa manera me evitaría el que pudieran verlo?

Comment: Puedes desactivar la visibilidad del panel de filtros cuando esté en modo lectura. Leete este enlace https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/power-bi-report-filter

Answer (score 0):

Los filtros que pongas en el panel de filtros pueden ser vistos y modificados por un usuario una vez publicados. Para evitar esto podes hacerlo invisible seleccionando el ojito que está en el panel de filtros antes de publicarlo.